# BIP Ethereum Key Generation -- Hardened Keys

Tags: private-key, public-key

You may know what the term hardened key is as it relates to the BIP-32 key generation method. If so would explain why the term 'hardened' is used to refer to the numbers which are about 2**31 through 2**32 - 1? Is it harder to crack with brute force hence the name?
Thank you!

SOLVED: LINKS INCLUDED IN ANSWER

Comment: Hi there. This has already been answered on the Bitcoin Stack Exchange site. -> https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/37489/27622

Comment: To add to the answer, [hardening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardening_(computing)) is a common term for reducing surface of vulnerability.